# Reference request for q-numbers?

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, quantum-groups

Let $q$ be an element of a field $k$ (possibly $\mathbb{C}$), different from $-1$ and $1$. We have 
$$[n]=\frac{q^n-q^{-n}}{q-q^{-1}}=q^{n-1}+q^{n-2}+\dots+q^{-n+1}$$

Where $n$ is a natural number.

I know some basic facts about this type "number"s when $n$ is natural. I am wondering about the case when $n$ is not a natural number (or the more general case like what we have in the case of factorials, I mean the gamma function)? Could anyone possibly direct me to a reference that talks about the general case.

Is there a specific name for this "number"?

*ps feel free to tag the right keyword

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might find this book useful: "Quantum Calculus" by Victor Kac and Pokman Cheung, Springer, 2002.

http://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387953410

Answer (score 2):

These are q-numbers. Rev. F. H. Jackson and E. Heine made them into more useable forms, ie Bessel, Hypergeometric, and so on function.
The q-numbers are naturally defined by
\begin{align}
[n]_{q} = \frac{1-q^{n}}{1-q}
\end{align}

[q-numbers, Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-analog)

[q-gamma integrals by Alberto De Sole , Victor G. Kac](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0302032.pdf)

Many many more papers are readily found. G. E. Andrews and a few others have books packed with q-functions

---

The q-numbers defined by
\begin{align}
[m] = \frac{q^{m} - q^{-m}}{q - q^{-1}}
\end{align}
are used in symmetric algebra structures of quantum mechanics.